# Vector Imported curves not moving on Z axis

Tags: bezier-curves

I wanted to make some 3D infographics, so I imported some vector images into blender via Inkscape. Normally, I can edit and move the points on a curve through all three dimensions, but for some reason these will only move on the x and y axes. 
I want to make the arrows point up and around as well, but this kinda impedes it. 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a **2D curve** implies that the Local Z coordinate of each control point is 0.

[image]

From the [Blender manual's page](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/introduction.html#shape) about the topic:

> By default, new curves are set to be 3D, which means that Control Points can be placed anywhere in 3D space. Curves can also be set to 2D which **constrain the Control Points to the Curve’s local XY axis**.

In a 2D curve you can't even set it's origin's Z coordinate with the 3D cursor. It is forced to lay on the plane where the the control points are.

You should switch the curve nature to 3D to be able to move them up and down.

Comment: I think I tried that before, and the plane that was created from the points got totally bizarre. I'll try it again though....

Comment: I know, handlind 2D curve is much easier. Their are just 2D. When converting to 3D curves, there are more things to consider to make it look right.

Comment: So would it be easier to fix these curves, or just hand model my own using the others for reference? I added the what it looks like up there.

Comment: It depends on which way you are going to use them, your projet's goals... Anyway I would use them, the difficult part is handling a 3D curve, not drawing the 2D contour.

Comment: Consider that until you don't have faces the Solidify modifier can't help. http://postimg.org/image/4k9pkwt4d/ And remember to adjust the Normal size with an appropriate value for your geometry size